# SQL request : how to make a particular select with multi tables and calcul?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's my problem. I've 4 tables on an Oracle Database:

- Team(teamID, teamName)
- TeamMembers(membersID, teamID, membersStatusID)
- Members(membersID, membersName)
- Status(membersStatusID, statusName)

I need to gets the `teamName`, the numbers of `teamMembers` in these teams and the name of the members who have the status "Captain"... all of this in one `SELECT` in SQL.

Many hours on this and no solution... any idea?

Edit: I need to see all teams, even if there's no members in it.

Comment: is there only one captian on each team??

Comment: Each team has no or 1 captain only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on my oracle, so there may be some slight syntax issues here, but I'll give it a shot:

```
SELECT t.teamName,
  count(*) AS teamMembers,
  c.membersName as teamCaptain
FROM team t
  INNER JOIN TeamMembers tm ON tm.teamID = t.teamID
  LEFT JOIN Members m ON m.membersID = tm.membersID
  LEFT JOIN TeamMembers tmc ON tmc.teamID = t.teamID AND tmc.memberStatusID = "Captain"
  LEFT JOIN Members c ON c.membersID = tmc.membersID
  GROUP BY t.teamName, c.membersName
```

Edit: Forgot the GROUP BY line!

Comment: pretty sure you need a group by somewhere. :)

Comment: Thanks all ! i've looked the last solution and it's works. I've just replace the "INNER JOIN" by a "LEFT JOIN" to have all teams in the select.  Last question so, the COUNT(*) is always starting at 1. Is it possible to have "0" for teams without members ?

Comment: Try replacing count(*) with count(m.membersID)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.team_id, t.teamName, count(tm.teamid), m.membersname
from team t, teammembers tm, members m, status s
where t.teamid = tm.teamid (+)
and tm.membersid = m.membersid (+)
and m.membersstatusid = s.statusid (+)
and s.statusname = 'Captain'
group by t.team_id, t.teamName, m.membersname
```

Comment: if you have this sentence (and s.statusname = 'Captain'), you'll have a full join, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
teamName,
b.[Number Of Members],
c.membersName AS [Captian]
FROM
Team
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS [Number Of Members],
    teamID
FROM
    TeamMembers
GROUP BY
    teamID
) AS b ON Team.teamID = c.teamID
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    membersName,
    teamID
FROM
    Members
INNER JOIN
    TeamMembers ON Members.membersID = TeamMembers.membersID
INNER JOIN
    Status ON TeamMembers.memberStatusID = Status.memberStatusID AND Status.statusName = 'Captian'
) AS c ON c.teamID = Team.teamID
```

May Work. Might need to tweak it though because of the group by in the b select statement. Also I wrote this in sql only since I dont know oracle syntax

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to test this select now, but you can try this:

```
select team.teamName,count(distinct members.membersID) numMembers,
MAX(CASE when status.statusName='CAPTAIN' then members.membersname else null END) Captain
from team,teammembers,members,status 
where team.teamID=teammembers.teamID(+)
and teammembers.membersID=members.membersID(+)
and teamMembers.memberStatusID=status.memberstatusID(+)
group by team.teamName;
```